# data migration old DB to new DB -- triggers? output clause? what?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to migrate data from parent and child tables in an old DB into similar tables in a new DB. The old and new schemas are different.

In the old DB the parent entry has (ID, ...) and the child entries each have (ID, pid, ...), where pid is the ID of the corresponding parent row.

The question is, how do I get them connected in the destination DB? I'm stuck. I had thought the way to do it would be to create a table that maps oldID to newID for each element; however, I cannot figure out how to do that with either triggers, output clause or anything else I've looked at.

There are other tables I'd like to migrate as well, so that oldID to newID mapping table would be handy. Unless there's a better solution.

To explain further... There are foreign key relationships in the old DB that need to be preserved in the new DB. But when a row gets copied to the new DB it gets a new PK. Rows in Child tables have as FK the old PK of the parent row. In order to copy child rows from the old DB into the new one I have to select them from the old DB with the parent's old PK but insert them into the new DB with the parent's new PK. That's the part I can't figure out how to do with SQL.

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Are both databases on the same server?  Is this a one time conversion, or an ongoing need? Do the destination tables already contain data?

Comment: @Nathan Both DB on same server. Destination tables already contain data (so I can't do the identity insert thing). It's only ongoing when I think of other things that would be nice to have. I don't really want to move everything. The old data would be useful for testing the new app (1k people, 20k ledger entries, etc, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another approach:

Simply add an `IDMap` column to the target database table, insert related tables based on a join to the `IDMap`.

E.g. For tables

```
CREATE TABLE db1.dbo.Parent
(
  Id int identity,
  description varchar(max),
  PRIMARY KEY(Id)
)

CREATE TABLE db1.dbo.Child
(
  Id int identity,
  ParentId int NOT NULL,
  SomeChar char(1),
  PRIMARY KEY(Id),
  FOREIGN KEY(ParentId) REFERENCES db1.dbo.Parent(Id)
)

CREATE TABLE db2.dbo.Parent
(
  Id int identity,
  description varchar(max),
  PRIMARY KEY(Id)
)

CREATE TABLE db2.dbo.Child
(
  Id int identity,
  ParentId int NOT NULL,
  SomeChar char(1),
  PRIMARY KEY(Id),
  FOREIGN KEY(ParentId) REFERENCES db2.dbo.Parent(Id)
)
```

Your import script could be:

```
ALTER TABLE db2.dbo.Parent ADD IDMap INT
--might consider adding an index for performance, might help, might hurt.
GO

INSERT INTO db2.dbo.Parent (description, IDMap)
SELECT description, Id FROM db1.dbo.Parent

INSERT INTO db2.dbo.Child (ParentId, SomeChar)
SELECT db2.dbo.Parent.Id, db1.dbo.Child.SomeChar
FROM db1.dbo.Child
INNER JOIN db2.dbo.Parent ON db2.dbo.Parent.IDMap = db1.dbo.Child.ParentId
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/05850/3) demonstrating the above (not strictly speaking cross database because of sql fiddle limitations, but should give you the idea.)

You can then drop the `IDMap` column, or keep it if you want it around for posterity.

Comment: This is nice. I haven't tried it yet but as I've been mulling it over it seems this method accommodates everything I need to do. Thanks.

Comment: It works very well. Got the data moved that I needed. It took several iterations against a local copy of the DB to get all the column values converted correctly. But the fundamental technique of adding a column *in the destination DB* was the key. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

We'll can't you just write an INSERT query for new DB with SELECT from old DB?

Something like this should work:

```
INSERT INTO NewDB.schema.TableName (newCol1, newCol2, ... ,newColN)
SELECT oldCol1, oldCol2, ... , oldColN 
FROM OldDB.schema.TableName
```

I also think that high end data comparison tools such as [ApexSQL Data Diff](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_datadiff.aspx) and [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) offer some kind of advanced table mapping that will allow you to do this automatically. I dont really think you need any of these tools for this but they may come useful.

Comment: That works great when you have only one table to create. But there are foreign key relationships in the old DB that I need to preserve in the new one. See the edit above...

Comment: I see now. This makes it a bit more complex.
"But when a row gets copied to the new DB it gets a new PK" - I guess this happens because you have identity enabled on your PK columns. Can you simply disable identity columns and/or disable foreign key constraints and then enable them again?

Comment: I've done that before; however, I was hoping there was a solution that could be done on a 'live' DB. It can be done in C# of course. It just seemed like there ought to be a way to do this in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

OK I have a solution; however, it seems so *coded*. Anyway, after the following loop runs the fidToGroupId table can map an old DB ID into a new DB ID. Now family members whose FKs once pointed to the old Family ID can now be mapped to the new Group ID with a JOIN and inserted into the new DB

I was hoping there were a more elegant (and less tedious!) solution than just grinding through the rows like this.

```
use phdb 

declare @GroupId int
declare @UserId int
declare @ClientId char( 11 )

select @ClientId = min( ID ) from mcndb.dbo.tClient where IsPerson=0
while @ClientId is not null
begin
    -- Old.Family becomes New.Group
    insert into Groups (GroupName, GroupKind)
        select (fname + ' ' + lname) as GroupName, 'Family' 
            from mcndb.dbo.tClient where ID = @ClientId
    set @GroupId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    -- Map fid to GroupId for later use
    insert into mcndb.dbo.fidToGroupId (fid, GroupId)
    values (@ClientId, @GroupId)

    -- Create a user for parent of the family group 
    insert into Users (FirstName, LastName, IsFemale, DoB, ProviderUserKey)
        select fname, lname, 0, '1977-07-07', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
            from mcndb.dbo.tClient where ID = @ClientId 
    set @UserId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    -- Connect the parent into the group
    insert into UsersInGroups (Group_ID, [User_ID], [Role])
        values (@GroupId, @UserId, 'PayingParent')

    -- Next row
    select @ClientId = min( id ) from mcndb.dbo.tClient 
        where ID > @ClientId and IsPerson = 0
end
```